# Multiple For loops, print else only once if condition is not met

Tags: python

There is a loop in a loop, if condition is met some code runs. However, if condition is not met, I need it to print something. Though if I add code to any location, it is printed multiple times. How to make it print only once, if condition is not met?

```
some_list = {'a_list': [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Val', 'age': 25}], 'b_list': [{'name': 'Don', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Tim', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'San', 'age': 25}]}

findperson = 'San'

for i in some_list:
    for y in some_list[i]:
        if y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower():
            print('Friend found')
            break
else:            
    print('Friend not found')
```

Comment: @ValdemarT what exactly is the output you are after?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `any` for the inner loop (and `break` from the outer loop)...

```
for i in some_list:
    if any(y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower() for y in some_list[i]):
        print('Friend found')
        break
else:            
    print('Friend not found')
```

... or even for the whole thing:

```
if any(y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower() 
       for i in some_list for y in some_list[i]):
    print('Friend found')
else:            
    print('Friend not found')
```

If you also need the actual friend, you can use `next`:

```
for i in some_list:
    friend = next((y for y in some_list[i] if y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower()), None)
    if friend is not None:
        print('Friend found:', friend)
        break
else:            
    print('Friend not found')
```

Also works with nested generator, like with `any` above:

```
friend = next((y for i in some_list for y in some_list[i] 
                 if y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower()),
              None)
if friend is not None:
    print('Friend found:', friend)
else:            
    print('Friend not found')
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using flags and `break` (which only breaks the inner loop) another possible solution would be to use a function. This way you can simply use `return`. This also has the benefit of stopping the search once a match is found.

```
some_list = {'a_list': [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Val', 'age': 25}],
             'b_list': [{'name': 'Don', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Tim', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'San', 'age': 25}]}

search_name = 'San'

def find_person(data, name_to_find):
    for i in data:
        for y in data[i]:
            if y['name'].lower() == name_to_find.lower():
                print('Friend found')
                return
    print('Friend not found')

find_person(some_list, search_name)
```

Comment: I would rather have the function return the actual friend, though, and then do the printing outside of the function.

Comment: @tobias_k I agree, but I'll let OP implement that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
some_list = {'a_list': [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Val', 'age': 25}], 'b_list': [{'name': 'Don', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Tim', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'San', 'age': 25}]}

findperson = 'San'

found = False

for i in some_list:
    for y in some_list[i]:
        if y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower():
            print('Friend found')
            found = True
    if found:
        break
if not found:            
    print('Friend not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

`for else` is a good trial with `break` condition, but it only works when you get 1-for loop, but here you get 2-for loop, you can use a flag:

```
some_list = {'a_list': [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Val', 'age': 25}], 'b_list': [{'name': 'Don', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Tim', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'San', 'age': 25}]}

findperson = 'San'
found = False

for i in some_list:
    for y in some_list[i]:
        if y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower():
            print('Friend found')
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        break

if not found:
    print('Friend not found')
```

Comment: The problem is it still runs the loop after it finds the person you're looking for. This is just a minor setback though, and does nothing but slightly slows down the computer.

Comment: @Jacob The real solution would be to have the nested loops in a function so `return` can be used instead of `break` and a flag, or use a different data-structure altogether.

Comment: you are right, I should break out as soon as possible @Jacob

Answer (score 1):

The best option imo is to put the nested for-loops in a function and return when you have found your friend, but if for some reason this isn't possible, you could end your nested for loops prematurely when you have found your friends without using a flag by doing something like

```
some_list = {'a_list': [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Val', 'age': 25}], 
             'b_list': [{'name': 'Don', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Tim', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'San', 'age': 25}]}

findperson = 'San'

for i in some_list:
    for y in some_list[i]:
        if y['name'].lower() == findperson.lower():
            print('Friend found')
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
else:
    print('Friend not found')
```